# jquery popup needs to know which element caused the event

Tags: jquery, html, dhtml

I have the following javascript that uses the qtip library for creating a javascript pop up.  I'm not sure how to gain access to which li element within the collection was clicked. 
Is this possible?  I've added an alert box within the code below to help explain the problem.  Let me know if you need anything else!
Many thanks,

```
$('li').each(function () {
    $(this).qtip(
    {
        content: {
            text: 'test text',
            title: { text: true, button: '<img src="/Images/close.gif">' }
    },
    position: {
        corner: {
            target: 'rightMiddle',
            tooltip: 'leftMiddle'
        },
        adjust: {
            screen: true
        }
    },
    show: {
        when: 'click',
        solo: true
    },
    api: {
        beforeShow: function(index) {
            if(document.getElementById('basketCheck')) {
                alert('what LI caused this click?');
                return false;
            }
        }
    },
    hide: 'unfocus',
    style: {
        tip: true,
        border: {
            width: 0,
            radius: 4,
        },
        width: 264,
        height: 195,
        title: { 
            background: '#ffffff'
        },
        lineHeight: '16px'
    }
})
```

});

Comment: As a note, the callback function for `beforeShow` is passed an event as its parameter; calling that `index` makes no sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The triggering element is available in the `elements.target` property of the qTip instance. That instance, in turn, is bound to `this` in `beforeShow` handlers:

```
api: {
    beforeShow: function() {
        if(document.getElementById('basketCheck')) {
            // This <li> caused the click.
            var sourceElement = this.elements.target;  
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can I close the popup after the sourceElement line?  thank you

Answer (score 0):

Via the contextual `this`.

```
beforeShow: function(index) {
    //'this' points to the affected LI
}
```